# Migration of Active MQ version from 5.5.1 to 5.11.2

Tags: activemq-classic

Planning to migrate Active MQ version form 5.5.1 to 5.11.2 how to migrate the existing messages from older version(5.5.1) to newer version(5.11.2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question probably belong to "server fault" as it's not programming related. I posted an answer anyway. Just a heads up for future posts.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have already taken care of any migration issues noted in each release note from 5.6.0 to 5.11.2.

There are essentially two ways to upgrade/migrate a broker.

1. Simply install the new broker and point out the old (kahaDB) database. This will automatically upgrade to a new version. This may cause some downtime during store upgrade (at least if there are a lot of messages in the store).
2. Have two parallell brokers running at once and let the old "fade out". You can setup a shiny new 5.11 broker side by side. This also makes it possible to migrate to other store types (JDBC or LevelDB). It's a little more work but will keep you uptime maximized. If you depend on message order, I would not recommend this method.

   1. Setup the new broker.
   2. Remove transportConnector from the old broker, and add a network connector from old to new.
   3. Stop old, start new, start old.
   4. Now, clients (using failover, right?) will fail over to the new broker and messages from the old brokers will be copied over to new as long as there are connected consumers on all queues.
   5. When no more messages are left on old broker, shut it down and uninstall.

As with all upgrades, bypassing a lot of versions will make the upgrade less reliable. I would try some dry run upgrade of a production replica to ensure that everything goes as planned.